# Swift, allKeys, array, dictionary, order

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I want to convert below code into swift, Actually i want do not want to loose order of keys using allKeys of nsdictionary

```
 NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeys];
keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not want to lose order of keys" ? You want the keys to be ordered by id or not ?

Comment: No there is no particular filed on the base of which i can apply some order and get array according to that filed.

Simply, the keys in NSDictionary are custom strings, but i am getting random order while applying allKeys method of NSdictionary.

Comment: swift dictionary is an UNORDERED collection. random order of keys given by myDictionary.keys is normal behavior, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in Swift:

```
let myDictionary = ["100" : "foo", "2" : "bar"]

let keys = myDictionary.keys.sort {
    $0.compare($1, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending
}

print(keys) // ["2", "100"]
```

`myDictionary.keys` gives a (lazy collection) of all the dictionary
keys and can be sorted. In contrast to
`sortedArrayUsingComparator` (which takes a block returning `-1`, `0`,
or `+1`), the `sort()` method takes a closure returning
a *boolean* value which is `true` if the lhs is "smaller" than the
rhs.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3.0** version

```
     let myDictionary = ["100" : "foo", "2" : "bar"]

     let keys = self.myDictionary.allKeys.sorted {
                ($0 as AnyObject).compare($1 as! String, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending
            }
print(keys) // ["2", "100"]
```

`.orderedDescending` is used to sort the array in descending order where as `.orderedAscending` is used to sort the array in ascending order.

Comment: Too cumbersome : `$0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending` (and not `..descending`) . Further `allKeys` does not compile in Swift (3)

Comment: `allKeys` is an API which belongs to `NSDictionary`, however `myDictionary` is a Swift `Dictionary`.